# L'Hôpital's rule exercise concerning trig function

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

I'd like to verify that my work on the following L'Hôpital's rule question is correct:

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\,\,{\cot{x}\,(x^2+3x)} $$

As the limit evaluates to $\frac{0}{0}$, we take the derivative of the top and the bottom and evaluate the limit as a new fraction:

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\,\,{\cot{x}\,(x^2+3x)} = \lim_{x \to 0}\,\,\frac{\cos{x}\,(x^2+3x)}{\sin{x}} $$

$$=\lim_{x \to 0}\,\,\frac{-\sin{x}\,(x^2+3x)+\cos{x}(2x+3)}{\cos{x}} $$

$$=\frac{-\sin{0}\,(0^2+3\cdot0)+\cos{0}(2\cdot0+3)}{\cos{0}} $$

$$=\frac{0+3}{1} = 3$$

Hence,

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\,\,{\cot{x}\,(x^2+3x)} = 3$$

I'd appreciate any feedback on this calculation.  Thanks!

Comment: it's the right answer. you could've written $\cot$ as $\frac{1}{\tan}$ and it would've been easier

Comment: Was considering that, but I find it useful to see the original 'sine' and 'cosine' functions as I know that sine needs to become a cosine when x->0 in order to evaluate properly.

Comment: @ptikobj: You can also have $\frac{x}{\sin x}\cdot (x+3)\cdot \cos x$.

Comment: Looks good to me! Another way to calculate the limit is to note that $\sin x \sim x$, $\cos x \sim 1$ as $x\rightarrow 0$, so $\tan x \sim x$, $\cot x \sim 1/x$.